# How to share a hardware abstraction struct without making it global

Tags: c, struct, embedded, global-variables, abstraction

This is a question about sharing data that is "global", mimicking a piece of addressable memory that any function could access.

I'm writing code for an embedded project, where I've decoupled my physical gpio pins from the application. The application communicates with the "virtual" gpio port, and device drivers then communicate with the actual hardware. The primary motivation for this is the comfort it allows me in switching out what pins are connected to what peripheral when developing, and to include things like button matrices that use fewer physical pins while still handling them as regular gpio device registers.

```
typedef struct GPIO_PinPortPair
{
    GPIO_TypeDef     *port;       /* STM32 GPIO Port */
    uint16_t          pin;        /* Pin number */
} GPIO_PinPortPair;

typedef struct GPIO_VirtualPort
{
    uint16_t          reg;        /* Virtual device register */
    uint16_t          edg;        /* Flags to signal edge detection */
    GPIO_PinPortPair *grp;        /* List of physical pins associated with vport */
    int               num_pins;   /* Number of pins in vport */
} GPIO_VirtualPort;
```

This has worked well in the code I've written so far, but the problem is that I feel like I have to share the addresses to every defined virtual port as a global. A function call would look something like this, mimicking the way it could look if I were to use regular memory mapped io.

**file1.c**

```
GPIO_VirtualPort LEDPort;
/* LEDPort init code that associates it with a list of physical pins */
```

**file2.c**

```
extern GPIO_VirtualPort LEDPort;
vgpio_write_pin(&LEDPort, PIN_1, SET_PIN);
```

I've searched both SO and the internet for best practices when it comes to sharing variables, and I feel like I understand why I should avoid global variables (no way to pinpoint where in code something happens to the data) and that it's better to use local variables with pointers and interface functions (like a "get current tick" function rather than reading a global tick variable).

My question is, given that I want to the keep the syntax as simple as possible, what is the best way to define these struct variables and then make them available for functions in other modules to use? Is it okay to use these struct variables as globals? Should I use some kind of master-array of pointers to every virtual port I have and use a getter function to avoid using extern variables?

Comment: I understand if the text was unclear. The LEDPort was supposed to be implied as defined in another source file. This isn't any actual production code, I wanted to keep the post shorter since its mostly a conceptual matter.

Comment: If you want to define a `struct` to be usable in multiple C sources, just put it into a header and include the header in every C source or other header where it is needed. As the header might be included (indirectly) multiple times, you should use [Include Guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). (Some prefer `#pragma once` instead but I'm not a fan of `#pragma` in general.)

Comment: Doesn't this make it a global variable then? If that is the case, I would like to know if this is a good approach going forward or if I risk code smell due to a beginner mistake.

Comment: The definition of a `struct` (or `typedef` of a `struct`) just means to define a type (no memory allocation). You just tell the compiler "how a bundle of data would be layouted in memory". Only, declaring a variable (e.g. of this `struct`) means allocation of memory. So, the first sample code in your question defines types `GPIO_PinPortPair` and `GPIO_VirtualPort` - no memory allocation at all.

Comment: @Scheff I need to share the actual struct variables, not the definition. I hope this was clear in my post.

Comment: This can be achieved by declaring `extern` variables with these types. If multiple C sources (the official term is "translation units") declare an `extern` variable with same name, the linker will assign all these variables the same storage (i.e. address). One (and only one) of these translation units should provide a definition of the variable also. (Otherwise, the linker may complain "Undefined ...".)

Comment: The question was about best practices, not c fundamentals.

Comment: Sorry, for my mis-understanding...

Comment: Typically, vendor board support files *do* declare the hardware special function registers in a way that is global.  So that's clearly a very *established* practice.  It tends to mean the library access functions are effectively optional conveniences - you can use them, or if need be you can just manipulate register bits from anywhere in code.  "best practices" can be a very political term, and should keep in mind the limited applicability of ideas from large systems with memory protection to small systems often effectively without.

Comment: Hi mate. You try to reinvent the wheel. In the most embedded applications making the variable available globally is enough. Of course you can write the function which only can change this struct to make it safer. But it in my opinion it is **_"an abstraction to far"_** (if you do not understand what I mean read about the "Market Garden"). Anyway your idea goes too far in this direction

Comment: The abstraction collects different gpio pins from different ports into a single place, and additionally, gives a useful abstraction when using a LED or button matrix that multiplexes fewer pins into more peripherals that should still be addressed with a device register like variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to do it this way:

file1.h

```
typedef enum
{
  VirtualPortTypeLED
} VirtualPortType;

typedef struct GPIO_PinPortPair
{
    GPIO_TypeDef     *port;       /* STM32 GPIO Port */
    uint16_t          pin;        /* Pin number */
} GPIO_PinPortPair;

typedef struct GPIO_VirtualPort
{
    uint16_t          reg;        /* Virtual device register */
    uint16_t          edg;        /* Flags to signal edge detection */
    GPIO_PinPortPair *grp;        /* List of physical pins associated with vport */
    int               num_pins;   /* Number of pins in vport */
} GPIO_VirtualPort;
```

file1.c

```
GPIO_VirtualPort LEDPort;

void VirtualPortInit()
{
  /* fill in all structures and members here */
  LEDPort.reg = 0x1234;
  ...
}

GPIO_VirtualPort *VirtualPortGet(VirtualPortType vpt)
{
  switch(vpt) {
    case VirtualPortTypeLED:
      return &LEDPort;
  }

  return NULL;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include file1.h

GPIO_VirtualPort *myLed;

VirtualPortInit();
myLed = VirtualPortGet(VirtualPortTypeLED);
```

Btw, I didn't compile this ... :)

Comment: I understood the intent though! This was exactly what I was looking for. I especially like the enum that lets me just write what handle I want to grab!

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this without using a global struct that references a given set of hardware or a global set of addresses you create a handle to the GPIO struct at the location that you want when starting out.

I'm not sure how the STM32 is laid out as I have no experience with that family of devices but I have seen and used this method in the situation you describe.

If your hardware is located at a particular address in memory, eg: `0x50`, then your calling code asks a `GPIO_Init()` to give it a handle to the memory at that location. This still allows you to assign the struct at different locations if you need, for example:

```
/* gpio.h */
#include <stdef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <bool.h>

typedef struct GPIO_Port GPIO_Port; // forward declare the struct definition

GPIO_Port *GPIO_Init(void *memory, const size_t size);
GPIO_Write_Pin(GPIO_Port *port_handle, uint8_t pin number, bool state);
```

A simple implementation of the `GPIO_Init()` function might be:

```
/* gpio.c */
#include "gpio.h"

struct GPIO_Port // the memory mapped struct definition
{
    uint16_t first_register;
    uint16_t second_register;
    // etc, ordered to match memory layout of GPIO registers
};

GPIO_Port *GPIO_Init(void *memory, const size_t size)
{
    // if you don't feel the need to check this then the 
    // second function parameter probably won't be necessary
    if (size < sizeof(GPIO_Port *)) 
        return (GPIO_Port *)NULL;

    // here you could perform additional operations, e.g. 
    // clear the memory to all 0, depending on your needs

    // return the handle to the memory the caller provided
    return (GPIO_Port *)memory;
}

GPIO_Write_Pin(GPIO_Port *port_handle, uint8_t pin number, bool state)
{
    uint16_t mask = 1u << pin_number;
    if (state == true)
        port_handle->pin_register |= mask; // set bit
    else
        port_handle->pin_register &= ~mask; // clear bit
}
```

Where the struct itself is *defined* only within the source file and there is no single global instance. Then you can use this like:

```
// this can be defined anywhere, or for eg, returned from malloc(), 
//  as long as it can be passed to the init function
#define GPIO_PORT_START_ADDR (0x50) 

// get a handle at whatever address you like
GPIO_Port *myporthandle = GPIO_init(GPIO_PORT_START_ADDR, sizeof(*myporthandle));
// use the handle
GPIO_Write_Pin(myporthandle, PIN_1, SET_HIGH);
```

For the init function you can pass in the address of the memory with the real hardware location of the GPIO registers, or you can allocate some new block of RAM and pass the address of that.

Your addresses of the used memory do not have to be global, they are just passed to `GPIO_Init()` from the calling code and so ultimately could come from anywhere, the object handle takes over any subsequent referencing to that chunk of memory by passing to subsequent GPIO function calls. You should be able to build up your more complex functions around this idea of passing in the information that changes and the abstracted mapped memory such that you can still allow the functionality you mention with the "virtual" port.

This method has the benefit of separation of concerns (your GPIO unit is concerned only with the GPIO, not memory, something else can handle that), encapsulation (only the GPIO source needs to concern itself with the members of the GPIO port struct) and no/few globals (the handle can be instantiated and passed around as needed).

Personally I find this pattern pretty handy when it comes to unit testing. In release I pass the address for the real hardware but in test I pass an address for a struct somewhere in memory and test that the members are changed as expected by the GPIO unit - no hardware involved.